# Relationship Design

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, laravel-5, relationship

I'm building an app where clients can create a document from a pre-defined template, edit some fields with their own text and save it. I've sketched out the relations as I think they would be, and it's mostly fine to convert into Laravel:

[image]

The only question I have is how I'd handle the FieldValue relationship. The idea is that the Template defines all the fields, then rather than re-create these on each Document, it should just look to its Template for them. That would mean the FieldValue needs to look up to its Document, to the Template of that and find the corresponding Field from there.

Is there a clean way to implement this, or is there a better way of designing the relationship to make it more practical to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your diagram, looks like a pivot table with pivot data...

Which would generally be modeled like this in Laravel:

```php
class Document extends Model
{
    public function template()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Template');
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Field')->withPivot('value');
    }
}

class Template extends Model
{
    public function organisation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Organisation');
    }

    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Document');
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Field', 'App\Section');
    }

    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Section');
    }
}

class Section extends Model
{
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Document')->withPivot('value');
    }

    public function template()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Template');
    }
}

class Field extends Model
{
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Document')->withPivot('value');
    }

    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
    }
}

class Organisation extends Model
{
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Document', 'App\Template');
    }

    public function templates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Template');
    }
}
```

With related tables (if sticking with laravel defaults):

```
fields
    id - integer
    section_id - integer

documents
    id - integer
    template_id - integer

templates
    id - integer
    organisation_id - integer

sections
    id - integer
    template_id - integer

organisations
    id - integer

document_field
    id - integer
    document_id - integer
    field_id - integer
    value - string
```

Then you can access things many different ways. Here is one example:

```php
$user = App\User::find(3);

$organisation = $user->organisation;

foreach ($organisation->documents as $document)
{
    foreach ($document->fields as $field)
    {
        echo $field->pivot->value;
    }
}
```

And inserting:

```php
$field = App\Field::find(2);

$document = App\Document::find(4);

$value = 'My field value';

$document->fields()->save($field, ['value' => $value]);
```

Relevant docs:

- [Many-to-many relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many)
- [Querying relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations)
- [Inserting related models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models)
- [Working with pivot tables](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)

Comment: I'm giving this answer the accept + 100 bounty; I actually used part of Arjan's answer (consolidating templates and sections, and combining the formatting into a single table) but this answer was more helpful in the main problem I had

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you meant:

```
$doc = Document::findOrFail(Input::get('docId'));
$sections = $doc->template->sections;
$fieldValues = $doc->field values;
```

Now you simply run on the field values and get the field and the section and start placing stuff.

For better performance I would eager load the fieldValue parameters with:

```
->with('field');
```

Comment: Are you suggesting manually iterating both the fields and field values to match them up based on key name (probably done in the instantiation code for the Document)? If so, I was hoping to figure out some way of structuring it so that happens more organically - if not, could you clarify please? :-)

Comment: I mean you can iterate over fieldValue and for each one you can get the field and the section easily.

Answer (score 1):

**To give a answer to you're first question:**

I suggest that you call it **content**. You can handle the content as you're doing now. The relationship as is is good enough. You've to do that separated from the other tables.

**Second question: a better way**

I've created a ERD myself based on you're ERD:
[image]

I've changed a few thinks.

1. Not so important but a document is from a user.
2. Templates can have sub templates. The consequence of this is that you can reuse sub templates. E.g. if you've a logo you can just place that in you're document every time.
3. Due to the new template table you don't need sections anymore. With the new approach you can define sub sections/templates.
4. Properties are all put into one table. With this approach you can define infinite properties for fields. This can be allot more flexible. These are referenced to a field and the content. The content_id however isn't needed. I've just placed it there so you can easily check which field it applies to.
5. The main point of you're question was the FieldValue/Content. The content is referenced to the document. From the document you can fill in the fields of the template.

I hope this is clear for you. The advantages I see are:

1. More flexible in properties
2. Content lookup is easy and referenced to a field

I haven't changed anything on the content table. Just leave it as is. It's good that way! Hope this helps you. If you use [Schema designer](http://www.laravelsd.com) you can retrieve you're models very easily!

Comment: I accepted and awarded the 100 bounty to fungku as his answer was a little clearer, but I intended to start another 50-rep bounty to award to you answer as several points you made were very useful; in particular, pointing out that templates and sections can be merged together, as can formatting methods. Unfortunately, I have to double any subsequent bounty I award, so I'm not creating a 200-rep bounty. You have my thanks though, if it's any good :-)

Comment: I can deal with it :) I hope my advise was helpfull.